# Selecting records from a database from today plus the day tommorow

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select records in my database from the date today plus the date tommorow. Every time I execute this code, it shows the records from the date today onwards.

I have tried looking/searching everywhere and cannot find anything.

Here is my code.

```
SELECT sum(qty) FROM rooinventory where arrival <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and room='$a'";
```

Any advice?. Thanks

Comment: Is arrival a DATE or a DATETIME/TIMESTAMP column?

Answer (score 1):

Use `between`

```
SELECT sum(qty) FROM rooinventory 
where arrival between curdate() and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
and room='$a'";
```

or

```
SELECT sum(qty) FROM rooinventory 
where (arrival = curdate() or arrival = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
and room='$a'";
```

Comment: i have tried all of those but why is it that it shows all records?? of my table rooinventory?

Comment: What data type does `arrival` have. And can you show example data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `arrival` column is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME item, you need to use this query:

```
WHERE arrival >= CURDATE()
  AND arrival  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

This seems a little strange, but the thing is this:  a DATETIME such as '2014-08-14 08:15:00' is *not* less than or equal to '2014-08-14': it occurs after midnight on that date. Using the strict inequality `<` and adding an extra day to the ending time always works correctly, because it accepts `arrival` values up to but not including midnight on the last day you're interested in checking.

The `BETWEEN` keyword is not suitable for DATETIME or TIMESTAMP comparisons because of this.

Answer (score 0):

If arrival is of the datatype DATETIME or TIMESTAMP then you've got to add two days to your upper limit. As juergen has pointed out you've got to set a lower limit too. And to be very exact it's better to use < as Ollie Jones has pointed out in a comment to my answer.

```
SELECT 
    sum(qty) 
FROM 
    rooinventory 
where 
    arrival >= CURDATE() AND arrival < CURDATE + INTERVAL 2 DAY 
AND room = '$a'";
```

**Explanation**

```
SELECT CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

returns for the 2014-08-14

```
2014-08-15 00:00:00
```

If your arrival column is of type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` then all values of tomorrow that are not at midnight won't be included in you result.

Comment: `BETWEEN` isn't right here; you need a `<` comparison for the end of the range.

Comment: @OllieJones Good point but the upper limit will be at 2014-08-16 00:00:00. Does this really matter in this case we're assuming? But I edited it in.

Comment: thanks for your concern guys.. i will try suggestions now.. :)

Comment: using `<=` (or `BETWEEN`) will pull in any record with an exact midnight timestamp on the day *after* the desired range of time. But you want those left out.

Answer (score 0):

Use date_add function

Example:-

SELECT DATE_ADD('2005-05-24', INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK('2005-05-24')) DAY)

Try this for your query:-

DATE_ADD( CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Look the link for more details:-
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add